# Mock inner function of a functional component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

My functional component has a few functions to handle the events from html elements and they have some instructions incompatible with Jest (without adding new libs).

Is it possible to mock these inner functions (that are not exported)?

Here's an example:

Component.js

```
export default function MyComponent() {

  const setTouchPosition = e => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    // .. a few lines omitted for readability
  };

  const draw = e => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // .. a few lines omitted for readability
  };


  // a few more lines
}
```

Comment: Which part of the WebAPI can you not call in jest? Is it `canvas.getContext('2d');` ?

Comment: Every function or property related to the HTMLCanvasElement, including getContext (there are a bunch of them). I'd need to install the jest-canvas-mock lib and I don't really need to test the behaviour of this canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not mock inner functions, so the right thing to do here would probably be to refactor such that it is more easily testable.

For example, you could break out an inner component which consumes a custom `draw` rather than defines one, then the outer component would pass down your concrete current draw implementation.

Then you can test the inner component with a passed in mock.

Comment: I should add you could also just import draw from a file then mock it -- but IMO, making stuff more testable is a noble goal anyway